# different padding, if next div has same class as previous

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, styles

I want to give lower margin-bottom for siblings which has same class, except `:last-child`

```
<style>
    .text {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
</style>
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="text myText"></div> <!-- margin-bottom this 5px; -->
<div class="text myText"></div> <!-- margin-bottom this 5px; -->
<div class="text myText"></div> <!-- margin-bottom this 20px; -->
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="text myText"></div> <!-- margin-bottom this 20px; -->
<div class="text"></div>
```

Comment: this might work `.text{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.text.myText{
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.text + .text:not(.myText){
  margin-top:20px;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CSS doesn't have previous or parent selector, you can use the `margin-top` by this way:

```css
.myText + .myText {margin-top: 5px;}
.text:not(.myText) + .myText,
.myText + .text:not(.myText) {margin-top: 20px;}

div {border: 1px solid #99f;}

.text:not(.myText) + .myText:last-of-type,
.text:not(.myText) + .myText:last-of-type {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="text">No Bot Margin</div>
<div class="text">No Bot Margin</div>
<div class="text myText">margin-bottom this 5px;</div> <!-- margin-bottom this 5px; -->
<div class="text myText">margin-bottom this 5px;</div> <!-- margin-bottom this 5px; -->
<div class="text myText">margin-bottom this 20px;</div> <!-- margin-bottom this 20px; -->
<div class="text">No Bot Margin</div>
<div class="text myText">margin-bottom this 20px;</div> <!-- margin-bottom this 20px; -->
<div class="text">No Bot Margin</div>
```

This is the closest I can get you. Also it looks like your logic is not consistent.

Comment: can't I use margin-bottom, rather then margin-top? I just wanted to overwrite margin-bottom for myText css, since all the margins are coming as default  with our chat application. don't want to break it by changing anything else..

Comment: @Basit I understand, but as I said you the reason, CSS can go only from top left to bottom right. It cannot travel on the opposite side, so unfortunately no. `:(`